# copy paste exact row height from one workbook to other

Tags: excel

Name                    Value              Description
xlPasteColumnWidths      8                 Copied column width is pasted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

is there any value to to copy and paste row height just like column?

i am using this code to paste formats and column widths.
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=8, Operation:=-4142, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4122, Operation:=-4142, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

is there any way i can paste row heights as well?
i found these values (8 and -4122) in the link i provided but there is no value for row height

Comment: Hi Kiran, welcome to Stack Overflow. You have tagged c# and vb.net, however it seems you are asking about excel columns? Can you edit / rephrase your question to give us some more understanding of the problem you have. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a question

Comment: Hi Kiran, the paste special with Formats ( -4122) will paste the row heights, however, ONLY if the entire row selection is selected, if you only have to one cell selected ie A1 and paste special with formats, it wont paste the row height, if you select enitre row 1:1, and perform the same, it will update the row height. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine.